# Calculating rolling betas in matlab without for loop

Tags: matlab

I am calculating rolling betas for a huge number of assets in matlab using the [ecmmvnrmle](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/finance/ecmmvnrmle.html) (Multivariate normal regression with missing data) but this is taking a lot of time. Is there a way to do that without using a loop ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the issue you encounter. What do you have got so far?

Comment: currently i have two nested for loops. the outer loop runs through the colums in panel data. the inner loop calculates rolling betas by taking last 22 day data. As the number of assets i am dealing with is huge .. close to 2000. it takes significant amount of time to run through the loops. is there a way to be more efficient

Comment: Please provide a minimum (non-)working example.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code I am using

```
 for i=1:numcol-2 % col have various assets
temp_component = regress_dataset(:,i); %calculating returns
if strcmp(type, 'Equity')
   temp_component = price2ret(temp_component);
elseif strcmp(type , 'Corp')
   temp_component = diff(temp_component);
end 

  for j=1:numrows - roll - 1 %calculating rolling betas
    temp_index = indexset_ret(j:j+roll-1,:);   %index return for last 22 days (roll=22)
    temp_index(:,1) = 1;
    temp_asset = temp_component(j:j+roll-1,:);
    msr(j,:) = [size(temp_index),size(temp_asset) j];
    if sum(isnan(temp_asset))> 0
    ts_beta(j,k) = NaN;
    else
    [Param,Covar] = ecmmvnrmle(temp_asset,temp_index); %calculating beta
    ts_beta(j,k) = Param(2); %storing beta
    end
  end
 k=k+1;    
 end
```